# Why can't set `document.getElementById("text"); ` to be global?

Tags: javascript

Here is my 60 seconds counttime code,it operates successfully.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start=Date.now();
    function showtime(){
        var c=document.getElementById("text");
        var nowtime=60-Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
        c.innerHTML="left time is "+ nowtime +" seconds";
    }
    function countTime(){
        var c=document.getElementById("text");
        c.innerHTML="left time is 60 seconds";             
        setInterval("showtime()",1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="countTime()">
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here `var start=Date.now()` to make start a global variable,why `var c=document.getElementById("text");` can't be written below the line `var start=Date.now();` to make variable c as global var?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start=Date.now();
    var c=document.getElementById("text");
    function showtime(){
        var nowtime=60-Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
        c.innerHTML="left time is "+ nowtime +" seconds";
    }
    function countTime(){
        c.innerHTML="left time is 60 seconds";             
        setInterval("showtime()",1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="countTime()">
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please to explain why the program cannot be run when to set `document.getElementById("text");`  as global in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work, but in your second example at the time the script runs and tries to find the element, it isn't there because you neither used `window.onload` nor did you put your script below the html. Don't put javascript in the head. Rearange the code to

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body onload="countTime()">
<div id="text"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start=Date.now();
    var c=document.getElementById("text");
    function showtime(){
        var nowtime=60-Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
        c.innerHTML="left time is "+ nowtime +" seconds";
    }
    function countTime(){
        c.innerHTML="left time is 60 seconds";             
        setInterval("showtime()",1000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it'l work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only require a DOM element to be available when your code runs, you may also use the **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)** event and keep your code in the head:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

Then you put all your code in the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading your `<script>` in the `<head>` file, which means the script is fully loaded before the body is generated.

In your first snippet, c=document.getElementById("text") is located in a function in your script.

Therefore, that statement only executes when the function is called.

That call happens after the body is loaded.

At that time, your `<div>` element with id="text" exists, so getElementById is able to find it, and c is properly defined.

When you move that statement outside to global scope however, the statement executes before the body is loaded (before your div is created).

As a result, document.getElementbyID("text") will not find anything, c will be set to undefined, and thus is of no use.